# Python JSON update and delete values of object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

im trying to make changes to the json file, rewriting objects values actually.
im having trouble getting it done, im finding the right object but i cant seem to change the objects in the txt file.

```
with open('customersFile.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for p in data['customers']:
    if p['myPassword'] == userPassword:
        p['name'] = input('Enter new name: \n')
        p['phone'] = input('Enter new phone: \n')
        p['id'] = input('Enter new id: \n')
```

Comment: You just read the json file but didn't write it back.

Comment: You're not writing the new data back to the file.

Comment: Once done, you must open again the file (in `'w'` mode this time) and store back the `data` object.

Comment: `with open('customersFile.txt','w') as json_file:`

Comment: how do i store back the information? wrap it in an object and push it the same way i did when i created it?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 7.2.2. Saving structured data with json](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use json.dump:

```
with open('customersFile.txt', 'r+') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    for p in data['customers']:
        if p['myPassword'] == userPassword:
            p['name'] = input('Enter new name: \n')
            p['phone'] = input('Enter new phone: \n')
            p['id'] = input('Enter new id: \n')
        
    # reset file position
    json_file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)
```

Comment: thanks! works for me, but how do you delete the whole object from the file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only modifies the `data` object, not the file on disk.
You need to write the modified JSON object back to disk afterwards:

```
with open('62809614.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data['customers']:
        if p['myPassword'] == userPassword:
            p['name'] = input('Enter new name: \n')
            p['phone'] = input('Enter new phone: \n')
            p['id'] = input('Enter new id: \n')

with open('62809614_modified.json', 'w') as json_file_modified:
    json.dump(data, json_file_modified)
```

Simply use the same filename to overwrite the original file.